# local Variable may not have been initialized and a loop

Tags: java, methods

I have a program that originally took two numbers passed the values to a method and returned the higher number.  I got that so I decided to expand to the program and want the program to ask the user for the 2 numbers.  I have 2 problems that I can not figure out.  The first is that it is saying that my variables i and j are not initialized.  The second is that the program loops 3 times. can someone offer me any assistance. I am coming from c# Thanks.

```
package javabook;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int k = max(num1(i),num2(j));
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);       
        num1(i);
        num2(j);

        System.out.print("The maximum between " + num1(i) + " and " + num2(j) + " is " +k);
    }

    //Return the max between two numbers
    public static int max(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result;

        if (num1>num2)
            result = num1;
        else
            result = num2;      
        return result;      
    }//End Max Method


    public static int num1(int i)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
        input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        return i;
    }//End num1 method
    public static int num2(int j)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
        input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        return j;
    }//end num2 method


}
```

Comment: Well, they aren't initialized.

Comment: *scratches head* I gathered that lol. When I set them to 0 it kept the value of 0.

Comment: java is similar enough to C# that this should make sense; you can't call a method with two parameters that have no values... you need to initialize them (by getting input in this case). Also, passing `int i` to your num methods won't edit their values, as they aren't ever assigned using `i = input.nextInt()` which would allow you to return them.

Comment: Additionally, just editing the values isn't enough, since they are primitive, local variables. You don't need the parameter, just assignment and return.

Comment: finally, your output shouldn't include calls to the methods, since that will prompt the user for numbers again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variable don't have same values as globally declared variable's thus you have to assign some value to use them. Global variable int has value 0 by default.

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
or 

this.i = 0;
this.j = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
    int i;
    int j;   <---creates the var, but doesn't initialize it
    int k = max(num1(i),num2(j));
                             ^---using the var, without having initialized it
```

even a simple

```
j = 0;
```

would help.